# How to print positions in array index in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to assign a number to each letter of the alphabet and print strings using the numbers 0 through 25.

Creating array: `alphabet = ('A'..'Z').to_a`

Printing array: `puts alphabet[6,8].join` gives me an output of `GHIJKLMN`, which is not what I was expecting. Expectation is for it to print: `GI`

Additionally, if I try: `puts alphabet[6,8,15].join` I get the following error: `wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1..2) (ArgumentError)`

I am using Ruby 2.3.1. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the `[6,8,15]` syntax?

Comment: I'm attempting to print any word. Let's say I wanted to print "CHEESE"

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain what, *precisely*, is unclear to you in the documentation of `Array#[]`. That way, the Ruby developers can improve the documentation so that future developers do not stumble on the same roadblocks that you did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `#values_at` to get the array's values at multiple indexes:

```rb
alphabet = ('A'..'Z').to_a
alphabet.values_at(2, 7, 4, 4, 18, 4).join

#=> "CHEESE"
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

[`Array#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) is quite versatile. You can pass an index:

```
alphabet[6] #=> "G"
```

an index and a length:

```
alphabet[6, 2] #=> ["G", "H"]
```

or a range:

```
alphabet[6..8] #=> ["G", "H", "I"]
```

If you want to fetch the values for multiple indices, there's [`values_at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Array.html#method-i-values_at):

```
alphabet.values_at(6, 8, 15)
#=> ["G", "I", "P"]
```

which also supports ranges:

```
alphabet.values_at(6..8, 15)
#=> ["G", "H", "I", "P"]
```

or repeating the same index:

```
alphabet.values_at(2, 7, 4, 4, 18, 4)
#=> ["C", "H", "E", "E", "S", "E"]
```

Comment: I was going to suggest `[6,8,15].map{|i| alphabet[i]}.join`, but the `values_at` syntax is cleaner.